# struct member character by character in c

Tags: c, struct, char

How can I assign values to struct member *character by character*. I would like to do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s
{
    char  *z; 
};

int main ()
{

   struct s *ss;
   ss = malloc(2 * sizeof *ss);

   char *str = "Hello World-Bye Foo Bar";
   char *a = str;
   int i = 0;
   while (*a != '\0') {
       if (*a == '-')
           i++;
       else ss[i].z = *a; // can I do this?
       a++;
   }   
   for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
      printf("%s\n",ss[i].z);
}
```

So I can get something as:

```
ss[0].z = "Hello World"
ss[1].z = "-Bye Foo Bar"
```

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, the number of "-" in `str` might vary.

Comment: I like it better like this. welcome to SO :-)

Comment: The number of '-' in the string changing doesn't alter things much. You basically want to end up repeating the process I outlined so you terminate the previous string where you found the next '-' and call strdup again, but using the current string.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "sizeof struct s" (or "sizeof *s")?

Comment: struct s *ss;
   ss = malloc(2 * sizeof ss);

This should be "sizeof *ss" not "sizeof ss" because ss is a pointer to a struct. Edit: Lee-man got to it first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `const char *str` wasn't const you could insert a `'\0'` to split the string into two. You'd need to shift the other chars to the "right" as well in doing so.

The cleaner solution is to use something like `strdup` to make two copies of the string, one of which you terminate early, the other of which you start the copy partway through:

e.g.

```
ss[0].z = strdup(str);
ss[1].z = strdup(strchr(str, '-'));
const size_t fist_part = strlen(str)-strlen(ss[1].z);
ss[0].z[first_part] = 0;
```

**Update:** You can use this, even with more than one '-'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s
{
    char  *z; 
};

int main ()
{
  struct s *ss;
  ss = malloc(20 * sizeof(struct s));

  const char *str = "Hello World-Bye Foo Bar-more-and-more-things";
  int i = 1;
  char *found = NULL;
  ss[0].z = strdup(str);
  while ((found = strchr(ss[i-1].z, '-'))) {
     // TODO: check found+1 is valid!
     ss[i].z = strdup(found+1);
     *found = 0;
     ++i;
  }   
  for(i = 0; i<6; i++)
     printf("%s\n",ss[i].z);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In practice you want to be more careful to avoid bugs with unexpected inputs so you need to be sure you handle:

- There is no '-' char
- There is no '\0' char
- allocation failure

Don't forget to `free()` too!

Comment: @awoodland, thanks for your comment, I would prefer not to use strdup() in this case since I'm not sure how many "-" str will contain.

Comment: If you don't duplicate the strings or allocate extra memory some how you can't do this. The problem is to split the string you need to insert an extra '\0' char every time you want to break it up, but to do this you need to a) have spare "space" within the string and b) be able to legally modify the string, neither of which is possible without at least one call to malloc, and much cleaner with one call per fragment of the string you wish to keep.

Comment: @Mike: just updated my example to show how it would work with more than one '-' char in the string.

Comment: @awoodland: Great, Thanks! Now it is much clear to me what you were saying about strdup()

Comment: Just noticed I'd over complicated the truncation in the loop somewhat, so I've simplified it further.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  else ss[i].z = *a; // can I do this?
> ```

Yes, you can do that. **BUT** you need to allocate space for each `z` first ... and do not forget to NUL terminate the strings!

```
ss = malloc(2 * sizeof *ss);
ss[0].z = malloc(1000); /* don't do it */
ss[1].z = malloc(1000); /* like this!  */
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alloc new blocks of memory to hold the split strings (at least the first one).

```
char *s1, *s2, *a, *b;

const char *str = "Hello World-Bye Foo Bar";

s1 = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
s2 = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

a = str;

int i = 0;
ss[0].z = s1;
b = ss[0].z;
while (*a != '\0') {
    if (*a == '-') {
        i++;
        ss[i].z = s2;
        *b = ss[i].z;
        *b++ = *a;
    } else {
     // s[i].z = *a // can I do this? (yes, but it you might not be happy with the result :-)
        *b++ = *a; // try this instead...
    }
    a++;
}
```